# Nginx rewrite location

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx server with following configuration:

```
server {
    location /foo/ {
        proxy_pass https://192.168.0.21:6443;
    }

    location /bar/ {
        proxy_pass https://192.168.0.21;
    }

    location /other/ {
        proxy_pass https://192.168.0.21:7443/;
    }

}
```

What I need is

https://my.domain.com/foo/rest_of_url -> https://192.168.0.21:6443/foo/rest_of_url

https://my.domain.com/bar/rest_of_url -> https://192.168.0.21/bar/rest_of_url

https://my.domain.com/other/rest_of_url -> https://192.168.0.21:7443/else/rest_of_url

How should I config the server?

Comment: Your first two `location` blocks should work the way you want. To change `/other/` to `/else/` you will need to use: `proxy_pass https://192.168.0.21:7443/else/;`

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks Richard. How do I remove /other/?